# Get informed when listener has been attached to a Backbone.Model event

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

I'd like to know if its somehow possible to notify a Backbone Model that a listener has been attached to a certain event so it can react by doing some initialization process.

I'm asking, because I have a case where some events need too much costly preprocessing to just having the data available to fire a event that nobody listens to.

Is that possible at all with the Backbone Event system, or do I have to override the on() method?

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of ways to implement your idea.
Here is the first easy way:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, {

    subscribe: function (name, callback, context) {
        this.on(name, callback, context);
        this.trigger('bind:' + name, callback, context);
    }

});
```

So we will not override "on" method. We created own "subscribe" method. Here is usage example:

```
var Human = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.on('bind:change', function () {
            console.log('Someone started listening to "change" event');
        });
    }

});

var human = new Human({ name: 'Christian Engel' });

human.subscribe('change', function () {
    // do some stuff when a model's attributes have changed
});
```

But new method can make you confused. So we have an ability to override "on" for all the Backbone models:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, {

    on: function (name, callback, context) {

        var eventSplitter   = /\s+/,
            eventBinder     = /bind:/;

        Backbone.Events.on.call(this, name, callback, context);

        if (!eventBinder.test(name) && !eventSplitter.test(name)) {
            this.trigger('bind:' + name, name, callback, context);
        }

    }

});
```

Great! Now we can write pretty nice code:

```
var Human = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.on('bind:change', function () {
            console.log('Someone started listening to "change" event');
        });
    }

});

var human = new Human({ name: 'Christian Engel' });

human.on('change', function () {
    // do some stuff when a model's attributes have changed
});
```

And here is live demo / example / test:
http://jsfiddle.net/gmAL3/1/

Comment: A clever approach. I thought about this at first, too. But it would break attaching listeners to multiple events at once. And also doesnt work on specified events like change:key.

Comment: OK. Here goes a fix for multiple events. See my answer - it was updated.